# What is the difference between Routes and Jobs in Talend ESB?

Tags: routes, talend, jobs

They seem to be doing more or less the same thing - taking data, processing it and sending it out.

Internet search results show that Talend Routes are almost the same as Camel Routes, but that does not say anything about what they are and how are they different from Jobs.

What are the Routes and Jobs in Talend ESB?
What is the difference between them?
When to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Jobs are great at data integration. every component and row has rigid row dat structure. Routes are more flexible. They can have more dynamic payload, they offer more customization.  Jobs and routes are not entirely overlapping, each approach has its pros and cons. For jobs - there are already many pre-made configurable components, so for most of use cases you can be happy with them but routes are still a very good option if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Ihazkode I don't know what I am doing - hence the question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between Talend routes and jobs is that when you start a route, it listens indefinitely for input (file, message..etc), and whenever it is available it is processed and sent to destination ,until the route is stopped. On the other hand, a job is a batch process that is launched on demand to handle some input (files, database..etc) and ends when all input is processed.

Comment: But the Jobs I have seem to listen to REST requests and ActiveMQ messages indefinitely .. how come?

Comment: Actually, what I said about jobs is valid for most use cases but not all. You can make a job listen indefinitely for input by using some components (like the ones you're using) or loop components, but if you find yourself doing that you should consider using ESB routes as they are better suited for the job (no pun intended ;).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you then - you've just contradicted the answers main point -  *"The main difference between Talend routes and jobs .."*. How are they different then?

Answer (score 2):

Talend ESB jobs are exactly the same as the jobs you can make in other versions of Talend Studio (Data Integration Studio for example). **Talend jobs are best suited to the creation of ETL** (Extract-Transform-Load) data processes in which data needs to be Extracted, Transformed and Loaded between various types of object or system (i.e. databases, flatfiles etc.). Typically, you'd be talking about anything from small to large sets of data being processed over intervals greater than a few minutes or so. Talend ESB Studio takes the process you build in the Studio user interface and generates Java code in the background which allows your job to be executed when you click the run button. In enterprise versions of Talend, you can deploy these jobs to run on schedules, but it's also possible to export them by hand using the Studio itself.

Talend ESB Routes are quite similar to jobs in that they generate Java code in the background just as jobs do, but their use is **more suited to web services and messaging systems**, where you have smaller sets of data and want to transport it in near real-time. Most (if not all) of the generated code for Talend ESB Routes use a Java framework called [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/). Camel is used for creating [Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) (the scope of which is pretty huge), but you can think of it loosely as a set of tools for creating messaging systems. Routes aren't designed to be periodically run - rather they get deployed in some form of OSGi container (Apache Karaf for example, which is bundled with Talend ESB) and are more service-oriented.

An important point to note is that you can actually call Talend Jobs from a Talend Route if you want.